# CKEditor / KCfinder Upload (Yii2)

Tags: upload, yii2, ckeditor, yii2-advanced-app, kcfinder

I do not know what happened.
I can't upload files by ckeditor and Kcfinder on Yii2.
Yii2 Advanced form

I get the following warning message:

> 10.jpg: The uploaded file exceeds 64MB bytes. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVCpE.png))

---

File php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads=On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=64MB

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads=10

post_max_size=64M
```

File backend\views\information\ _form.php

```
<?php

namespace backend\modules;

use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

use iutbay\yii2kcfinder\KCFinderAsset;

class CKEditor extends \dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor
{

    public $enableKCFinder = true;

    /**
     * Registers CKEditor plugin
     */
    protected function registerPlugin()
    {
        if ($this->enableKCFinder)
        {
            $this->registerKCFinder();
        }

        parent::registerPlugin();
    }

    /**
     * Registers KCFinder
     */
    protected function registerKCFinder()
    {
        $register = KCFinderAsset::register($this->view);
        $kcfinderUrl = $register->baseUrl;

        $browseOptions = [
            'filebrowserBrowseUrl' => $kcfinderUrl . '/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
            'filebrowserUploadUrl' => $kcfinderUrl . '/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
        ];

        $this->clientOptions = ArrayHelper::merge($browseOptions, $this->clientOptions);
    }

}
```

File backend\modules\ckeditor.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use backend\models\Menulist;
//use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;
use backend\modules\CKEditor;
use iutbay\yii2kcfinder\KCFinder;
use yii\helpers\Url;


// kcfinder options
// http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/install#dynamic
$kcfOptions = array_merge(KCFinder::$kcfDefaultOptions, [
    'uploadURL' => Yii::getAlias('@web').'/upload',
    'access' => [
        'files' => [
            'upload' => true,
            'delete' => false,
            'copy' => false,
            'move' => false,
            'rename' => false,
        ],
        'dirs' => [
            'create' => true,
            'delete' => false,
            'rename' => false,
        ],
    ],
]);

// Set kcfinder session options
Yii::$app->session->set('KCFINDER', $kcfOptions);
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Information */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="information-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'menulist_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Menulist::find()->all(),'id','menulist_name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Menulist']
    ) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'information_detail')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'full'
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'information_status')->dropDownList([ 'active' => 'Active', 'inactive' => 'Inactive', ], ['prompt' => 'Status']) ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Your file is too big, have you set it to 64 mb by purpose in the php.ini file?